# exercicio sobre pointers

Tags: c

Implementa a função `void power_ref(int* x, int y)` que calcula a potência de `x` levando a `y`. O resultado deve ser colocado no endereço indicado no primeiro parâmetro, alterando seu valor inicial.

Tenho algo deste gênero:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void power_ref(int* x,  int y){

    int result = (int) *x ^ y;
    *x  = result;
    printf("result: %d", result);
}
```

Comment: Qual é a sua dificuldade no exercício?

Comment: Porque o `x` é um ponteiro e a função é `void`? Não seria mais simples e natural retornar o valor calculado?

Comment: é como pedem no ex , a dificuldade é com o pointer porque nao sei bem como usa-lo

Comment: coloquei o que tenho feito na pergunta em cima

Comment: Você sabe fazer uma função `int power(int x, int y)`? Se sim, poste-a que com base nela fica fácil fazer a `power_ref`.

Comment: O `^` no C não faz exponenciação. O `^` em C é o XOR (ou-exclusivo). Não é isso que você vai precisar usar. Vai precisar de um `for`.

Comment: para que um for?

Comment: Para fazer multiplicações sucessivas.

Answer (score 0):

Solução #1:

```
void power_ref( int * x, int y )
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = 1;

    for ( i = 0; i < y; i++ )
        n *= (*x);

    *x = n;
}
```

Solução #2:

```
#include <math.h>

void power_ref( int * x, int y )
{
    *x = pow( *x, y );
}
```

Solução #3:

```
void power_ref( int * x, int y )
{
    int n = 1;
    int b = *x;

    while(y)
    {
        if(y & 1)
            n *= b;
        y >>= 1;
        b *= b;
    }

    *x = n;
}
```

Teste:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int n = 2;

    power_ref( &n, 16 );

    printf( "%d\n",  n );

    return 0;
}
```